# how do I use the API do retrieve data on email clicks/opens?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to get data on click and open events for specific emails. I'm using the [FuelSDK python client](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Python).

In the Marketing Cloud email web UI I see an ID for one email I'm interested in  (an 8 digit number labeled "Email Send ID"). Let's call this the `webID` for a minute.

If I call the API with the `webID` (using the `FuelSDK.ET_Email` object), I get no results back. But if I search for the same subject/name I get back the a response for the same email, with a different `ID` (a 6 digit number). Let's call this ID the `ET_Email.ID`. I don't see the `webID` anywhere on this object.

If I request click events from the API (`FuelSDK.ET_ClickEvent` object) with the `ET_Email.ID`, I get no results. If I request with the `webID`, I get results, but the counts don't line up (at least one order of magnitude off) with what I see in the UI ([Email](https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/) under Tracking/Reports).

Will the API work for this use case? What am I missing?

Code:

```
import FuelSDK

client = FuelSDK.ET_Client(
    params=dict(clientid='xxx', clientsecret='yyy')
    )

subject = 'Test'
event = FuelSDK.ET_Email()
event.auth_stub = client
event.search_filter = {'Property': 'Subject', 'SimpleOperator': 'equals', 'Value': subject}
response = event.get()
print 'send_id:', response.results[0].SendID

# now let's try and get clicks
web_id = 12345678  # this is the webID of the email I'm looking for
event = FuelSDK.ET_ClickEvent()
event.search_filter = {'Property': 'SendID', 'SimpleOperator': 'equals', 'Value': web_id}
event.auth_stub = client
response = event.get()
print 'num_results:', len(response.results)
print 'more_results:', response.more_results
```

Result:

```
send_id: 654321      # does not match web_id
num_results: 301     # lower than the count in the UI by an order of magnitude
more_results: False
```

Comment: Are you looking for individual clicks on the subscriber level or the totals for an email send?

Comment: ideally individual subscriber-level clicks

Comment: FuelSDK.ET_ClickEvent and FuelSDK.ET_OpenEvent should be the ones you want.  When you are filtering on WebID where you get too many records back, it is possible you are comparing the UI numbers which are unique clicks/opens with the API values which are all clicks/opens? Please share your code.

Comment: added code. and, no the records count returned by the API is *lower* than the one in the UI.